# Pygame keyboard input doesn't works - Python

Tags: python, input, pygame, keyboard, key

Can someone help me ? When i press - A - on the keyboard , nothing happen

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption("PyGame")
pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))


while (True): 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type == pygame.K_a):
            pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pygame
import sys


pygame.display.set_caption("PyGame")
pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
pygame.init()

while (True):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if (event.key == pygame.K_a):
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: If you like this answer please mark it as solved to let other users
know your problem is solved. Also see [What should I do when someone
answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)